Why $\lim_{x \to 1^{+}} \frac{1}{f(x)} \frac{1}{x-1} = +\infty$?
From Product Rule for Limits (PRL) we have that
$\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x \to c} g(x) = M$.
Then $$\lim_{x \to c} [f(x) \cdot g(x)] = \lim_{x \to c} f(x) \cdot \lim_{x \to c} g(x) = L \cdot M.$$
In my case I want to compute the limit
$$\lim_{x \to 1^{+}} \frac{1}{f(x)} g(x),$$
where $\lim_{x \to 1^{+}} f(x) = L$ with $L>0$ real number and $\lim_{x \to 1^{+}} g(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^{+}} \frac{1}{x-1} = +\infty$. That is, in my case $M$ is not a finite number. As it seems, we can not apply the PRL in this case as $M$, i.e., the limit of $1/(x-1)$ as $x$ goes to $1^{+}$, is not a finite number. Are there other ways to prove that the limit equals to $+\infty$?

I feel like this is false in general. Consider $L<0$, in which case the limit would be $-\infty$.

What are you claiming that it is false?

@paulina thanks for the comment. I have $L>0$.

And is $L$ a real number?

@JoséCarlosSantos as far I understand, we can apply the product rule limit when $L$ and $M$ are finite numbers, In my case $M=+\infty$.

In general, $(\text{exists and } \ne 0) \times (\text{doesn't exist}) = \text{doesn't exist}$. If it did, you could divide both sides by $(\text {exists and } \ne 0)$ and get a contradiction to the limit of the second term on the LHS not existing. Intuitively, the existing term will serve as an almost constant factor which shouldn't help convergence

We can prove that
$\boxed{\;\\\text{ if }\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)=L>0\;\;\text{ and }\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+}g(x)=+\infty\;,\;\text{ then }\;\\\;\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+}\dfrac1{f(x)}g(x)=+\infty\,.\\}$
Proof :
Since $\;\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)=L>0\;,\;$ it follows that for $\,\varepsilon=\dfrac L2>0\,$ there exists $\;\bar{\delta}\!>\!0\,$ such that $\;-\dfrac L2\!<\!f(x)\!-\!L\!<\!\dfrac L2\;$ for any $\;x\!\in\!\big(x_0,x_0\!+\!\bar{\delta}\big)\!\subseteq\!\mathrm{dom}\,f\;$,
which implies that
$0\!<\!\dfrac L2\!<\!f(x)\!<\!\dfrac{3L}2\;$ for any $\;x\!\in\!\big(x_0,x_0\!+\!\bar{\delta}\big)\!\subseteq\!\mathrm{dom}\,f\;,$
$\dfrac1{f(x)}\!>\!\dfrac2{3L}\;$ for any $\;x\!\in\!\big(x_0,x_0\!+\!\bar{\delta}\big)\!\subseteq\!\mathrm{dom}\dfrac1f\;.\quad\color{blue}{(1)}$
For any $\;k>0\;,\;$ since $\;\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+}g(x)=+\infty\;,\;$ we have that
for $\,M\!=\!\dfrac{3Lk}2>0\;$ there exists $\;\delta_M\!>\!0\,$ such that
$g(x)\!>\!M\!=\!\dfrac{3Lk}2\;$ for any $\;x\!\in\!\big(x_0,x_0\!+\!\delta_M\big)\!\subseteq\!\mathrm{dom}\,g\;,\quad\color{blue}{(2)}$
consequently, from $(1)$ and $(2)$ it follows that
$\dfrac1{f(x)}g(x)\!>\!\dfrac{2M}{3L}\!=\!k\;\;\;$ for any $\;x\!\in\!\big(x_0,x_0\!+\!\delta^*_k\big)\!\subseteq\!\mathrm{dom}\dfrac gf\;,$
where $\;\delta^*_k=\min\{\bar{\delta},\delta_M\}>0\;.$
Hence,
for any $\,k>0\,$ there exists $\,\delta^*_k>0\,$ such that
$\dfrac1{f(x)}g(x)\!>\!k\;$ for any $\;x\!\in\!\big(x_0,x_0\!+\!\delta^*_k\big)\!\subseteq\!\mathrm{dom}\dfrac gf\;,$
that is , $\;\;\exists\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+}\dfrac1{f(x)}g(x)=+\infty\,.$

Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain a little more how we go from $\dfrac1{f(x)}g(x)!>!k;$ to the limit in the end? What is the intuition or what definition do we follow?

@Thoth, the definition of $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+}\dfrac1{f(x)}g(x)=+\infty,$ is the following one: for any $,k>0,$ there exists $,\delta^_k>0,$ such that
$;\dfrac1{f(x)}g(x)!>!k;$ for any $;x!\in!\big(x_0,x_0!+!\delta^_k\big)!\subseteq!\mathrm{dom}\dfrac gf;,$

You have$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac1{f(x)}g(x)=\infty,$$since$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac1{f(x)}=\frac1L\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac1{x-1}=\infty.$$If the limit of one of the factors is a real number greater than $0$ and the other limit is $\infty$, then the limit of the product is $\infty$.

Thanks for the answer. So we apply any definition here or we simply say that
as  $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to 1^{+}$ and $g(x) \to \infty $ as $x \to 1^{+}$ then $f(x)g(x) \to \infty $ as $x \to 1^{+}$. Sorry I haven't use limits since high school.

Actually, we prove what I wrote is true. It follows easily from the definitions.

You are correct, you cannot just apply the PRL to this problem. Instead, we can prove it as follows:
From the definition of a limit, we know there exists $\delta_0>0$ such that $x\in (1,1+\delta_0)$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\frac{L}{2}$. Then for these $x$ we have
$$-\frac{L}{2}<f(x)-L<\frac{L}{2}$$
$$\frac{L}{2}<f(x)<\frac{3L}{2}$$
$$\frac{2}{L}>\frac{1}{f(x)}>\frac{2}{3L}$$
Now, let $M>0$ be given. For $x\in (1,1+\frac{2}{LM})$ we have
$$\frac{1}{x-1}>\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{LM}-1}=\frac{L}{2}M$$
Putting this together, let $\delta_1=\min\{\frac{2}{LM},\delta_0\}$. Then for $x\in (1,\delta_1)$ we have
$$\frac{1}{f(x)}\cdot\frac{1}{x-1}>\frac{2}{L}\cdot \frac{L}{2}M=M$$
and we are done.

Thanks for the answer. It confuses me a little the fact that you use $L$ both inside and outside the absolute value. Shouldn't be different constant? For example $|f(x)-L|< \delta$.

So the definition of the right hand limit at $1$ is: for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $x\in (1,1+\delta)$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. In this case, since we know the limit exists, we are assiduously choosing $\epsilon$ to be $L/2$. We don't need an arbitrarily small bound for $|f(x)-L|$ for the proof, we just need $f(x)$ to be positive which is assured if we choose $\epsilon=L/2$
